# Inserting text between certain lines in a batch file using Python

Tags: python, text-files

I want to insert around 4000 lines of text from one text file to another but the list of text must be inserted between the current lines leaving empty line above and below it.

e.g. output.txt

```
old text

new text
new text

old text
```

all the 4000 lines are in the following format: `mydata /Alarm /Stop factor group1 cam.ad`
The number of lines will increase every week so I can't specify to just copy the 4000 lines.

Can anyone give me advice on how to do this? I tried some scripts but I was only able to edit the line with the specified text so it didn't work when the number of lines increased and it didn't save them in the output file.

I tried the following script:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('input.txt', inplace=1):
 print line,
 if line.startswith('old text'):
     print 'new text'
```

Comment: Sounds like a great application for sed if you're on *nix.

Comment: @JLewis can you show your attempts, also where exactly do you want to insert the lines?

Comment: @jamylak I want to insert the lines in an existing text file after line 21 and before the last 3 lines.

Comment: but do you want to overwrite `old`, or to generate `new` from `old` each time you call the script?

Comment: @zmo I just want to insert the lines in between the old text (the text that is already there.)

Comment: indeed, but in practice, as I tell you in my answer, it's best to create a new temporary file, and then overwrite the old file. I don't think you'll get a better answer than the one I'm giving if you're not giving actual code you're writing, and show what's wrong or where you are blocking writing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to work it out using an algorithm close to this:
here I consider `new` being the text that has to be imported into `old`.

open two files, the original one, and a temporary one `tmp`

1. read all lines up to 'old text', and write them in `tmp`
2. insert `\n` in `tmp`
3. insert `newtext` in `tmp`
4. insert `\n` in `tmp`
5. insert 'old text' and all following lines in `tmp`
6. copy the `tmp` file over `old` file

basically, in python that would look like

```
with open('oldfile') as old:
    with open('newfile') as new:
        with open('tmpfile') as tmp:
            …
```

sadly, without more context, I can't give you a better answer.